# how to increase character sequence in sql if given random number of table rows?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm currently studying SQL language in Oracle.
After making very simple `STUDENT` table, I thought about how to make character sequence in `ID` field.

For example, if `STUDENT` table has 6 rows, I want the `ID` field to be inserted by `'a','b','c'...'f'` characters respectively. And another condition is that the `ID` sequence should be ordered by age in ascending order.

The below explanation is about `STUDENT` table description and current inserted value (`ID` field is currently empty).

```
NAME            AGE      GRADE    ID
hi              15         1   
dui             12         2
giyu            16         3
hero            27         4
power           55         3    
rai             37         4
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
DESC STUDENT
NAME           VARCHAR2(20)
AGE            NUMBER(5)
GRADE          NUMBER
ID             VARCHAR2(12)
```

I hope many brilliant ideas come up here =)

until now, this is very easy to come up with making table ordered by age.
but inserting character sequence respectively is ... well .. idea doesn't come up now. And this is not homework. i just want to practice sql language.

Comment: An example of the values you hope for in the `id` column might help us understand. Please [edit] your question to clarify.  What happens if you have 27 rows (so you run out of letters)? What happens if you have millions of rows?

Comment: I would suggest you do this as a view instead of an actual column on your table otherwise you will have to adjust probably via triggers everytime you update delete and insert

Comment: Sounds like homework, which is not a problem in itself.  But you really should try to solve it yourself first, and let us know if and where you run into specific problems.

Comment: after 27 letters, it restarts from letter 'a'.

Comment: who a sort order in the first case ?

Comment: yougest one, such as select name,id from student order by age asc;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update tableX X
   set ID=(
           select ID from (
                select rowid as rid,
                       chr(mod((row_number() over (order by age))-1,26)+97) as ID
                  from tableX T
               )
            where rid=X.rowid
          )
```

Required order of the ID set in the `over(order by )` clause. Function `row_number()` gets sequence number of rows in given order. `mod()` gets remainder of the division (for 26 chars only). `chr()` get char by the ascii code.

Comment: Mike, your answer helps me a lot and if you hadn't informed me of the way of approach, i would have got lost for a long time because i didn't know chr() function.                                -------------------------------------------update student x set ID=( select ID from ( select rowid as rid, chr(mod((row_number() over(order by age))-1,26)+97) as ID from student T) where rid=x.rowid);----------------------------------------------------this is the query i used =) Thanks Mike!!

Comment: @BlackHair If there were no `chr()` it is necessary to `create table CHARS(N number, C char(1)); insert into CHARS values(1,'a') .... (26,'z')`... :)

Comment: I'll think about it too. I guess i need time to fully understand your query. you helped me a lot =)